# getting variables to call for a function c++

Tags: c++

So basically im trying to do a program that formulates distance between two points in a 3-d world. I'm trying to call on a function to do the formula called distance. But my problem was trying to get the input for all 6 variables. Could of done it one by one but that makes the code large and a bit to much. So instead tried to use an array to take in values but its coming up with errors like 'no matching function for call to 'distance float[6]'

Simply put im trying to take in 6 variables using an array then send them to the function to find the distance between them

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

float distance(float ux, float uy, float  uz,
                   float vx, float vy, float vz);
int main()
{
    float number = 0.0f;
    float loopArray[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
    cout << "Enter x,y,z of first coordinates to find distance between x,y,z second cordinates" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cin >> number;
        loopArray[i] = number;
    }

    distance(loopArray);

}


float distance(float ux, float uy, float uz,
                   float vx, float vy, float vz);
{
    sqrt (((ux - vx) * 2) + ((uy - vy) * 2) + ((uz - vz) * 2)) = float dist;

    return dist;
}
```

Comment: The function takes six arguments of type `double`, not an array of `double`s.

Comment: this really calls for a simple 3D point class.

Answer (score 4):

Your function is declared to take 6 float variables as arguments. If you need to call it with an array add an overload that takes an array as argument. Something of the sort of:

```
float distance(float a[]) {
  return distance(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);
}
```

This function simply calls the other version that has six arguments. A better options is to modify the original function to take an array as argument.

Answer (score 1):

Ivalyo has already explained the overload, however I'd like to note that, if you want to compute the Euclidean distance between two points, your `distance` function is incorrect. The `*` operator is multiplication, not exponentiation; the correct expression might look something like

```
return sqrt(((ux - vx) * (ux - vx)) + ((uy - vy) * (uy - vy)) + ((uz - vz) * (uz - vz)));
```

I've also skipped the temporary variable, since it's not necessary and I'm not even sure the "post-assignment" is valid C++.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

- You said `distance` would take six `double`s, but gave it a whole array of them. Either change its signature or pass them one by one.
- The syntax

  `sqrt (((ux - vx) * 2) + ((uy - vy) * 2) + ((uz - vz) * 2)) = float dist;`

  makes no sense. You meant

  ```
  float dist = sqrt (((ux - vx) * 2) + ((uy - vy) * 2) + ((uz - vz) * 2));
  ```

  although that's not technically correct: you need to take the square of these terms.